# I'm trying to print the largest number from the inputs that the user gives, but it's printing the wrong number

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop, input

Basically, I'm trying to build a code to get the largest number from the user's inputs. This is my 1st time using a for loop and I'm pretty new to python. This is my code:

```
session_live = True
numbers = []
a = 0

def largest_num(arr, n):
    #Create a variable to hold the max number
    max = arr[0]

    #Using for loop for 1st time to check for largest number
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max:
            max = arr[i]

        #Returning max's value using return
        return max

while session_live:
    print("Tell us a number")
    num = int(input())

    numbers.insert(a, num)
    a += 1

    print("Continue? (Y/N)")
    confirm = input()


    if confirm == "Y":
        pass

    elif confirm == "N":
        session_live = False
        
        #Now I'm running the function
        arr = numbers
        n = len(arr)
        ans = largest_num(arr, n)
        print("Largest number is", ans)

    else:
        print(":/")
        session_live = False
```

When I try running my code this is what happens:

```
Tell us a number
9
Continue? (Y/N)
Y
Tell us a number
8
Continue? (Y/N)
Y
Tell us a number
10
Continue? (Y/N)
N
Largest number is 9
```

Any fixes?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the built-in `max()` function?

Comment: `return max` should be at the same indentation level as the `for`, not the `if`.

Comment: @KenY-N WOAHH IT FIXED, cool ty, nevermind, its not working still

Comment: @Barmar I think yeah, but don't take it from me, I'm still very new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first things first,

- the use of `max` can be avoided, as it is a reserved keyword in python

And coming to your fix, you are comparing it with the value only once in the loop, and you are returning the number, the indentation is the key here. You will have to wait for the loop to complete its job then return the value.

- There are many inbuilt methods to do the job, Here is your implementation (a bit modified)

```py
session_live = True
numbers = []
a = 0

def largest_num(arr, n):
    #Create a variable to hold the max number

    max_number = arr[0]

    #Using for loop for 1st time to check for largest number
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max_number:
            max_number = arr[i]

    # --- The indentation matters
    #Returning max's value using return
    return max_number

while session_live:
    print("Tell us a number")
    num = int(input())

    numbers.insert(a, num)
    a += 1

    print("Continue? (Y/N)")
    confirm = input()


    if confirm == "Y":
        pass

    elif confirm == "N":
        session_live = False
        
        #Now I'm running the function
        arr = numbers
        n = len(arr)
        ans = largest_num(arr, n)
        print("Largest number is", ans)

    else:
        print(":/")
        session_live = False
```

Comment: Yeah, this works too thanks, I'm gonna keep both for reference in the future, anyway ty :D

Comment: Welcome. Maybe if you consider two answers, kindly upvote both. And have one as a chosen answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The error in your `largest_num` function is that it returns in the first iteration -- hence it will only return the larger of the first two numbers.

Using the builtin `max()` function makes life quite a bit easier; any time you reimplement a function that already exists, you're creating work for yourself and (as you've just discovered) it's another place for bugs to creep into your program.

Here's the same program using `max()` instead of `largest_num()`, and removing a few unnecessary variables:

```
numbers = []

while True:
    print("Tell us a number")
    numbers.append(int(input()))

    print("Continue? (Y/N)")
    confirm = input()
    if confirm == "Y":
        continue

    if confirm == "N":
        print(f"Largest number is {max(numbers)}")
    else:
        print(":/")
    break
```

Comment: thanks it works, but can you tell me what the "f" does in the if condition for N

Comment: That's an "f-string": https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

Answer (score 0):

I made it without using the built-in function 'max'. 
It is a way to update the 'maxNum' variable with the largest number by comparing through the for statement.

```py
numbers = []

while True:
    print("Tell us a number")
    numbers.append(int(input()))

    print("Continue? (Y/N)")
    confirm = input()

    if confirm == "Y":
        continue

    if confirm == "N":
        maxNum = numbers[0]
        for i in numbers:
            if i > maxNum:
                maxNum = i

        print("Largest number is", maxNum)

    else:
        print(":/")
    break
```